# How to create an ATLAS using second feature iteration on QGIS Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I'm looking forward to get deeper with QGIS ATLAS Composer features like we do with some reporting sofwares.

Today I try to map and iterate over parcels and display buildings attributes on the side, all buildings on a slide should be on the iterated parcel.

[image: Map from parcel + buildings on the left, Buildings attributes on the right]

The idea behind could be more a generic approach to list joint subfeatures from an iterated one used for the Atlas.

For my Use case:
Buildings and parcels have a geographical link and also keys to link each other.

**Update** : I add a better example to be more explicit. In this configuration, we could add buildings linked pictures (from the database urls using html), and so on...

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of features that intersect the atlas feature geometry very easily and their attributes.

Simply add an attribute table to the map. The attribute table can be filtered to "Show only features intersecting atlas feature".

[image]

Comment: Ty, I'm looking forward to have the same selection, but displaying attributes in a prettier way. Like we can do with the label objet or the html frame object. I have 2 issues, the first one is to select my data like you did with the table tool, and then create x objects on x positions.

Comment: What would happen if you have more than three buildings? The attribute table gives you a lot more flexibility. Also I don't think you can do it with labels.

Comment: That's exactly why I need to iterate on the second feature, but actually for my use case I have a small amount of buildings per parcel (3-4 max).

Comment: Do you know the exact max number of buildings that you need to iterate on? 
You could pre-build your buildings list in the composer (like the 3 you have in your example ) and then display the elements according to the effective number of buildings.

Comment: Actually I can have a count of max buildings per parcel, for the example let's say 3 buildings. What do you mean by "pre-build"? Do you mean modify the data structure to have in the parcel table the building1firstattribute, building1secondattribute, ..., building2firstattribute, building2secondattribute, ..., etc? That could be a workaround but far less elegant than the way the table did in @Vesanto's answer. The idea is simple, do the same as the table tool iteration, but on features like labels ("cosmeticly more attractive").

Comment: By "pre-build" I meant that you create the elements needed in the composer (the right part in your example) and then you conditionally display them if there is a sufficient number of buildings in the parcel (ie if there is info to display) or you can hide them with a white rectangle to do as if the element wasn't there